# Excel formula for returning a specific value everytime my progressive total increases by a certain amount

Tags: excel

I am having trouble creating Excel formula for returning a specific value every time my progressive total increases by a certain amount.

**Example:** I need to purchase 1300m of piping every time the tonnage profile increases by 15000 tons. Assuming my average tonnage increase is about 2700 per month. My progressive tonnages run from `C6:AS6`. My first month in `C6` is Jan 2015 that runs to Jul 2018. My specific value is in `C1`. My tonnage increment of 15000 tons is in `A3`. I tried the following formula but it still requires manual input every next increment (at 30000, 45000, 60000, etc)

```
If(C6>A3,C1,if(C6>(A3*2),C1,if(C6>(A3*3),C1,0)))
```

This formula still creates a problem because I still need to multiply it manually for every increment increase. Is there a way past this?

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
=CEILING(C6/$A$3,1)*$C$1
```

would that give you what you need - the total meters of piping?
Breaking it into increments of $A$3 (15000) times by the $C$1 1300m of pipe...

**EDIT** Original version stepped at >= rather than >...
Using `FLOOR(C6/$A$3,1) + 1` means that 15000 would need 2... If the switch should be at 15001 (which, looking at your formula it is - you use `CEILING`

Comment: Thanks @pnuts - that will teach me to type, not copy-paste :-)